# Cordova didn't build apk

Tags: java, android, cordova, environment-variables

I'm learning Cordova but from the start I've some problem building APK.

I think that probably is something about environmental variables.

When i try to run:

```
cordova build android
```

It tell me this error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Android (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.1
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

And this is how I've tried to set environmental variables:

[image]

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It complains about JDK `12.0.1`:

```
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.1
```

and demands [JDK 8](https://openjdk.java.net/install/index.html) instead of JRE 8. then one can change the `JAVA_HOME`:

```
set JAVA_HOME=<PATH TO JDK 8 - NOT JRE 8>
cordova build android
```

See the [release notes](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/16/cordova-android-release-8.0.0.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've installed JDK 8 and modified JAVA_HOME like the image.

[variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiFqx.png)

But the error is always the same.